# Upload file yii2 without extentions

Tags: php, file-upload, yii2, image-uploading

I am trying to upload a file without the use of any extension but the result is not successful. e.g. The pop up success upload is blank on the screen and I don't know why.

This my code siteController.php

```html
public function actionUpload()
{
    $model = new \app\models\UserPhoto();
    if (\Yii::$app->request->post()) {
        $model->photo = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'photo');
        $model->user_id = \Yii::$app->user->id;
        if ($model->validate()) {
            $saveTo = 'uploads/' . $model->photo->baseName . '.' . $model->photo->extension;
            if ($model->photo->saveAs(saveTo)) {
                $model->save(false);
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'foto berhasil di upload');
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->render('upload', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

This code for site\upload.php

```html
<?php
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\Html;
?>
<h1>Upload Foto</h1>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'] ]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'photo')->fileInput() ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>
<?php
ActiveForm::end();
?>
```

And this code for models\UserPhoto.php

```html
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['user_id', 'photo'], 'required'],
        [['user_id'], 'integer'],
        [['photo'], 'file', 'extensions' => ['png', 'jpg', 'gif'], 'maxSize' => 1024*1024]
    ];
}
```

Comment: What are the results of $model->validate(); and $model->getErrors();

Comment: You mean what ? I'dont understand

Comment: Write: var_dump($model->validate()); and var_dump($model->getErrors());

Comment: well... if your file validator states 'extensions' => ['png', 'jpg', 'gif'] your validation fails... http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-filevalidator.html#$extensions-detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a error in your code `saveTo`, which is not post back to modal.

`if ($model->photo->saveAs(saveTo))` should replaced with `if ($model->photo->saveAs($saveTo))`

Comment: That's code is fixed. and result is " PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException.
move_uploaded_file(uploads/bechmark.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory".

Comment: Instead of modal, try simple form and see results also check is file attached or not using this line `if(!empty($model->photo)` then call ` saveAs` function

Answer (score 0):

Here is my controller :

```
public function actionUpload_banner() {
    $model = new \app\models\my_model();
    $uploadedFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'banner_img');
    $model->banner_img = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'banner_img');
    if (!empty($model->banner_img)) {
        $myfile = rand(100, 1000) . '_' . $uploadedFile;
        $model->banner_img->saveAs('uploads/' . $myfile);
    } else {
        echo "Please Select File"; // if empty handle situation 
    }
    $model->banner_img = $myfile;
    if (!empty($model->banner_img)) {
        $model->save(FALSE);         // Save data in db

    }
}
```

here is my form.php

```
<div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['action' => [Yii::getAlias('@COMPANY_URL') . '/clients/upload_banner?client_id=' . $client_id], 'id' => 'banner_form', 'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
                <section class="col-sm-4">
                    <label><b>Select Banner Image : </b></label>
                </section>
                <section class="col-sm-8">
                    <?= $form->field($clientModel, 'banner_img')->fileInput()->label(false) ?>
                </section>
                <section class="col-sm-6">
                    <?= Html::submitButton($clientModel->isNewRecord ? 'Upload' : 'Update', ['class' => $clientModel->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary', 'id' => 'banner_save_btn']) ?>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger txt-color-white" role="button" id="banner_cancel" >Cancel </a>
                </section>
                <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
            </div><br>
        </div>
```

Here is my model :

```
[['banner_img'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],
['banner_img', 'required']
```

Comment: What mean : upload_banner?client_id=' . $client_id], 'id' => 'banner_form' ??

Comment: no serious... I am just sending client id to my upload banner action